# Can i play NES in ZSNES?

Tags: zsnes

Title says it. I've been looking for an alternative to Fceux since it just doesn't work on my computer and I thought: "Why not look for a way to run NES roms in ZSNES?". On my adventure to find the holly ZSNES plugin (if they even exist), I decide to ask ths community. And here I am, asking you how to do this.

Comment: You can't.  There are many more NES emulators than Fceux, so using one of those is your best bet.

Comment: But  I just wanna stick to ZSNES, because it works.

Comment: Then you can't play NES games.  ZSNES plays SNES games.  That's all it was meant for, and all it can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ZSNES aside from being a SNES emulator, does not support plugins, therefore a plugin to play NES games on ZSNES does not only not exist, but is impossible.

---

However, a hack is possible. You will not be getting fixes or updates... however, such hack has been done: [Z.N.E.S](http://board.zsnes.com/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=158858&p=385352&hilit=NES+ROMS#p385352). To download, you have to remove the "s" from the link in the post I linked to.

Note: You will need to get the Famicom Disk System from elsewhere and place it in the executable folder.

[VirusTotal Scan: mostly clean](https://www.virustotal.com/#/file/e50b9ee3a631f3570eee053dd02e92f667e049882ab41f4f55d5c79d5b5fef7a/detection) (1 out of 60 engines says it is unsafe).

I tested it with both SNES and NES roms. It works for *some* NES roms, otherwise it crashes (yes, it crashes with SNES roms). You might aswell get a proper NES emulator.

---

In my personal opinion, you should look what is out there, instead of trying to make it all work inside of ZSNES. You might even consider [other emulators for SNES](https://www.emulator-zone.com/snes/).

If your killer feature is to have a single interface for multiple consoles, there are [emulator frontend](https://lmddgtfy.net/?q=emulator%20frontend)s and [multi-system emulators](https://lmddgtfy.net/?q=multi-system%20emulators) that can help with that.

If all you need is a NES emulator because Fceux is not working for you, there are  [alternatives to Fceux](https://alternativeto.net/software/fceux/).

Answer (score 5):

ZSNES is a SNES emulator.  It can play only SNES games.  If you want to play NES games, you need to use a NES emulator, which were made to do so.